# Sending one big packet vs two little ones

Tags: tcp, server, socket.io

Currently I am sending 60 'sync' packets per second to the **server A**, and the **server A** also sends 60 different 'sync' packets per second to the client. Let's say that for now the packets latencies look like this:

- From client to **server A** - 30ms average.
- From **server A** to client - 35ms average.

Now I want the client to establish a connection with the **server B** and sometimes (also 60 times per second or maybe 20/10/5) send this **server B** some other packets 'different'. How sending packets to both server **A** and **B** will affect latencies described above? And in general if I send two packets simultaneously can they go to the server in parallel without disturbing each other?

Answer (score 0):

Sending packets at 60Hz means that each packet should be sent 16,6ms after the previous one. With 1Gbps network interfaces you can send up to nearly 2MBytes (or 200KBytes with 100Mbps interface) of data in that period, so it is very likely that you can send another 60 packets per second to server B without disturbing the packets sent to server A.

Respect to what happens if you send two packets simultaneously they won't exit simultaneously if they have to use the same network interface. The delivery of each packet to the network interface driver could be done in parallel if the server has several CPU cores and the driver has different queues for each core, but the exit of each packet to the network will be serialized, sending one after another. A network interface, at least an Ethernet one, can not send two packets to the network at the same time.